# Rewriting price filter

Tags: price, template, overrides, layered-navigation

I need to rewrite how filter looks, but there's no specific template for that the label rendering in Magento core, so what's the best way to edit how it looks?

The code in `Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php` so I need to change the label.

```
 protected function _renderRangeLabel($fromPrice, $toPrice)
{
    $store      = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $formattedFromPrice  = $store->formatPrice($fromPrice);
    if ($toPrice === '') {
        return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('%s and above', $formattedFromPrice);
    } elseif ($fromPrice == $toPrice && Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_ONE_PRICE_INTERVAL)) {
        return $formattedFromPrice;
    } else {
        if ($fromPrice != $toPrice) {
            $toPrice -= .01;
        }
        return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('%s - %s', $formattedFromPrice, $store->formatPrice($toPrice));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to change the label, you can use translation, it's limited but it may work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend `Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php` file you will need to create a simple module ([Learn here](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/)).

Your `config.xml` (rewrite section)

```
<global>
   <models>
       <catalog>
           <rewrite>
              <layer_filter_price>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price</layer_filter_price>
          </rewrite>
      </catalog>
   </models>
</global>
```

And create a file `NameSpace/MudleName/Model/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Price.php`

```
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price
{
 protected function _renderRangeLabel($fromPrice, $toPrice)
 {
    $store      = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $formattedFromPrice  = $store->formatPrice($fromPrice);
    if ($toPrice === '') {
        return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('%s and above', $formattedFromPrice);
    } elseif ($fromPrice == $toPrice && Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_PATH_ONE_PRICE_INTERVAL)) {
        return $formattedFromPrice;
    } else {
        if ($fromPrice != $toPrice) {
            $toPrice -= .01;
        }
        return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('%s - %s', $formattedFromPrice, $store->formatPrice($toPrice));
    }
 }
}
```

**Any changes on this function should get affected.**

Comment: Thank you, it's really the best way to do it, but still, I hoped there's more clear way to change it without extending